# Domain transfering

Tags: domain

I had booked a Domain which got expired last month. And yesterday I transfered my domain from my  existing registerer to name.com, but now name.com is not able to transfer the my domain for which I have already paid to the name.com, I contacted name.com they are saying first remove the whois info from the domain. but my old registerer are saying they cant because the domain is expired and now they are asking me to renew it from them. that will make me to pay twice for one domain :(
  Is there any way I can get transfer my domain without paying any more amount.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case, you will not get around paying twice (or cancelling your order with the new registrar).

The old registrar are keeping the domain name registered at their discretion, and they have probably already paid the renewal fees (which occur yearly and in advance). You will probably not be able to force them to transfer the domain to another provider for free.

**Lesson:** Take care of domain names *before* they expire. I've had to learn that, too, back in the day :)

Comment: Thanks for reply So I can cancel my booking from new domain. Does they will refund my full amount?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I just re-read your question, I now think you've registered a domain that expired for someone else.  In which case you can't transfer it for 60 days.  So you'll need to register it, then tranfer it later.  But then you're paying for time on the domain, which will transfer, so it's not a loss.

**ORIGINAL:**

The only way your registrar can stop the transfer is if the domain has only been registered or transferred in the last 60 days.

As long as the domain is still in the 45 day grace period expiration is not a valid reason to deny a transfer.

From the [ICANN website](http://www.icann.org/en/transfers/dnholder-faq-03nov04.htm):

> **My domain name has just expired. Can my registrar require me to pay for a renewal before I can transfer to a new registrar?**
>
> No. Your new registrar of choice can initiate a transfer request on an expired domain name once they receive the required authorization from you. Expiration or nonrenewal of a domain name is not a valid reason for denial of a transfer request.
>
> Note that if the registrar has already begun the deletion process on the domain name and its status shows it to be within a 30-day Redemption Grace Period, the name must be .restored. by your current registrar before it can be transferred.

Contact your old registrar and demand they release it.